# Line break removed in output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following script to get a list of all the services that are automatic but not running on a set of servers.

Code:

```
$Me = 'me@domain.com'

function Get-AutoServiceStatus
{
    $Servers = 'SRV1', 'SRV2', 'SVR3', 'SVR4'
    foreach ($Server in $Servers)
    {
        Write-Output "`nThe automatic services that aren't running on $Server are:"
        Get-WmiObject win32_service -Filter "StartMode = 'auto' AND state != 'Running'" -ComputerName $Server | select -ExpandProperty DisplayName | Format-List
    }
}

$Output = Get-AutoServiceStatus | Out-String
$Body = "Hi team,`n`nHere are the services that are set to start automatically on each of the listed servers, but aren't running.`n" + $Output + "Please take the necessary actions.`n`nRegards,`nBig Guy"

Send-MailMessage -From 'BigGuy@domain.com' -To $Me -SmtpServer 'smtpserver.domain.com' -Body $Body -Subject 'Post-reboot service check on Servers'
```

Console output:

```
The automatic services that aren't running on MySrv are:
Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X86
Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X64
Software Protection
Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)
```

Received email:

```
The automatic services that aren't running on SRV1 are:
Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X86Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X64Software ProtectionWindows Image Acquisition (WIA)
```

Desired email:

```
Some friendly text here

The automatic services that aren't running on MySrv are:
Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X86
Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X64
Software Protection
Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)

Bye
```

As in, I need each service name appear on a separate line. However, all the names of the services appear on the same line.

PS version: 3.0

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Ram

Comment: Without `| Out-String` I get the same result as you in my emails, but adding `| Out-String` solves this for me. I'm using PS version 5.

Comment: Have you tried using  rn (with tick, can't do it here) instead ?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Hmm... I have PS v3.

Comment: @majkinetor, backtick-m instead of backtick-n? No, the output gives about four objects in a shot. So how do I break the line between the output objects?

Comment: No, backtick-r, backtick-n together

Comment: @majkinetor No, the spaces are perfect wherever there's a backtick-n.  
The problem is with no linebreaks between the objects in the output.

Comment: It is possible that the email client is trying to be "helpful" and removing line breaks in the display of the message. View the raw email content to see whether the line breaks are really there. In any case, you can use HTML format for better control of the resulting message.

Comment: Fix for putting linebreaks between objects in the output: `$list = (command); $list -join "\`n"`

Comment: Yes, but the issue is that that I don't know how to place <br> tags between the output rows. The service names are all appearing in one single line, and I don't know how to control that...

Comment: @ryan, the console output is right, but the email output is still the same...all service names in a single line. Square one. :(

Comment: Looks like the `-ExpandProperty` is causing the issue.

Comment: If you want HTML breaks between lines, use `$list -join "<br/>\`n"`.  You can put any string you want between the items.

Comment: I'll try this and get back!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried formatting the email to HTML?

```
Function Send-Email {
$From = "email1@domain.com"
$To = "bigguy@domain.com"
$Body = "<strong>Date:</strong>"+(Get-Date)+"<br>"+"<strong>Hostname:</strong>$hostname<br>"+"`<strong>The automatic services that aren't running on MySrv are:</strong>.<br>$Output<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><h3 style=""color:red;"">*** This is an automatically generated email, please do not reply ***</h3>"

Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject `
    -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -BodyAsHtml
    }
```

Email:

```
Hostname: SERV1
Date:04/25/2016 11:55 AM
The automatic services that aren't running on MySrv are:
upnbphost
WinMgmt
*** This is an automatically generated email, please do not reply ***
```

Comment: OK, I'm gonna ask a stupid question now... It seems like the service names are being passed as text in the email—as in you're explicitly mentioning the names of the services. How do I get it to get the output to format it rightly?

Comment: Looks like the `-ExpandProperty` is causing the issue.

Comment: I would suggest adding the services name to an array and then passing the array to the body of the email.

Comment: I'll try this and get back. Thank you!